# UICollectionView example failing with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following the [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiiN9oFH3vE) on UICollectionView but I am coding it in Swift, using Xcode 6 and iOS SDK 8.0 (I've also tried using 7.1 and 7.0).

Here's my controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imagesArray:String[] = []
    let cellIdentifier = "CollectionCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imagesArray += "Swift"
        imagesArray += "is"
        imagesArray += "the"
        imagesArray += "next"
        imagesArray += "hotness"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        var label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel
        label.text = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0

        return cell
    }

}
```

I've set the CollectionViewCell's Identifier in Storyboard to `CollectionCell` and the Tag to `100`.
I'm getting the app to build but am getting this error at runtime:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
```

However, when I'm debugging, I'm noticing that `po indexPath` returns `nil`. Also, if I comment out all the code after the `let cell` call, the app runs.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, the reason why it is failing for you is that you need to set the UILabel's tag to 100 and not the UICollectionViewCell. That should fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks Salman, that fixed it. So the instructions are wrong. The Label's Tag needs to be set to 100, and then I just did `var label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel`. This also makes more sense. I wasn't sure why I had to use `viewWithTag` on a cell that I already got.